# Why do some movie titles include an alternate title?

Tags: title

> "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb"
>
> "Birdman (or The Unexpected Virtue of Ignorance)"

Why do some movie titles include an alternate title? What are the rules in constructing these titles?

Comment: In the case of Dr Strangelove I'm positive it's just for comedic effect. Birdman is likely just referencing Dr Strangelove.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also use the term **Subtitle (titling)**.

Generally, subtitle is given to a movie title to provide a hint or a little more information of the movie to the moviegoers.

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_%28titling%29) says,

> In books and other works, a subtitle is an explanatory or alternate title. For example, Mary Shelley used a subtitle to give her most famous novel, Frankenstein; or, the Modern Prometheus, an alternate title to give a hint of the theme. In library cataloging the subtitle does not include an alternate title which is defined as part of the title proper; e.g. "One Good Turn" (title proper) "A Natural History of the Screwdriver and the Screw" (subtitle); "Twelfth Night, or What You Will" (title proper).